# Android: Performance issue populating my (complex) ListView

Tags: android, performance, listview

I have a List of lines and every line has a List of Meals. What's the best way to populate my ListView? That's what it looks like right now: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ihX29.jpg and this is my Adapter:

```
public CanteenPlanAdapter(Context context, Plan plan) {
    this.context = context;
    if (plan != null) lines = plan.getLines();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    if (lines != null) return lines.get(position);
    else return null;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Line line = (Line) getItem(position);

    List<Meal> meals = line.getMeals();

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.canteen_list_group_item, parent, false);

    for (int i = 0; i < meals.size(); i++) {

        Meal meal = meals.get(i);

        View child = inflater.inflate(R.layout.canteen_list_child_item, null);

        TextView name = (TextView) child.findViewById(R.id.canteen_meal_name);
        name.setText(meal.getMeal());

        TextView price = (TextView) child.findViewById(R.id.canteen_meal_price);
        price.setText(String.valueOf(meal.getPrice1()) + " €");

        if (meal.isBio()) {
            ImageView bio = (ImageView) child.findViewById(R.id.meal_bio);
            bio.setVisibility(1);
        }
        if (meal.isCow()) {
            ImageView cow = (ImageView) child.findViewById(R.id.meal_cow);
            cow.setVisibility(1);
        }
        if (meal.isCow_aw()) {
            ImageView cow_aw = (ImageView) child.findViewById(R.id.meal_cow_aw);
            cow_aw.setVisibility(1);
        }
        if (meal.isFish()) {
            ImageView fish = (ImageView) child.findViewById(R.id.meal_fish);
            fish.setVisibility(1);
        }
        if (meal.isPork()) {
            ImageView pork = (ImageView) child.findViewById(R.id.meal_pork);
            pork.setVisibility(1);
        }
        if (meal.isVeg()) {
            ImageView veg = (ImageView) child.findViewById(R.id.meal_veg);
            veg.setVisibility(1);
        }
        if (meal.isVegan()) {
            ImageView vegan = (ImageView) child.findViewById(R.id.meal_vegan);
            vegan.setVisibility(1);
        }
        ((ViewGroup) convertView).addView(child);
    }
    TextView name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.canteen_line_name);
    convertView.setTag(name);

    name.setText(line.getName());

    return convertView;
}
```

It's working, but the performance is obviously pretty bad...  I tried using Viewholder, but I have no idea how to add the Meal List Items..

Answer (score 0):

To get acceptable performance in a ListView, you **must** reuse the item views. Creating and destroying them as you scroll will make the performance suffer a lot. So the first part is using the supplied `convertView` when it's not null (the ViewHolder pattern is a further optimization on this).

In this case the additional difficulty seems to be in the fact that each list item also has a different number of children depending on the ingredients. What you should do is reusing, plus only create more of these child views if you need more than you already have (and set the others as `GONE`).

A rough example (may not compile, use as guideline only) :)

```
if (convertView == null)
    convertView = inflate(R.layout.canteen_list_group_item);

ViewGroup group = (ViewGroup)convertView;

for (int i = 0; i < meals.size(); i++)
{
    View child;
    if (group.getChildCount() > i)
    {
         // We have enough views already, recycle one.
         child = group.getChildAt(i);
    }
    else
    {
         // We need an extra row.
         child = inflate(...);
         group.addView(child);
    }

    setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); // in case it was hidden previously.

    // Load this child
    TextView name = (TextView) child.findViewById(R.id.canteen_meal_name);
    <etc, same as before>
}

// Hide extra children
for (int i = meals.size(); i < group.getChildCount(); i++)
    group.getChildAt(i).setVisibility(View.GONE);

return group;
```

Of course, the indexes may have to be adjusted (i.e. not start at 0) if the `canteen_list_group_item` has other "fixed" child views, but I hope you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

First of all thank you for your chick response! I changed my Code based on your idea and it's working (kinda). canteen_list_group_item has 2 fixed child views (name and a divider line) so i adjusted the indexes:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    Line line = (Line) getItem(position);
    List<Meal> meals = line.getMeals();

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.canteen_list_group_item, parent, false);
    }
    ViewGroup group = (ViewGroup) convertView;

    for (int i = group.getChildCount(); i < meals.size() + 2; i++) {

        Meal meal = meals.get(i - 2);

        View child;
        if (group.getChildCount() > i) {
            child = group.getChildAt(i);
        } else {
            child = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.canteen_list_child_item, null);
            group.addView(child);
        }
        child.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        TextView name = (TextView) child.findViewById(R.id.canteen_meal_name);
        name.setText(meal.getMeal());

        TextView price = (TextView) child.findViewById(R.id.canteen_meal_price);
        price.setText(String.valueOf(meal.getPrice1()) + " €");

    }
    for (int i = meals.size() + 2; i < group.getChildCount(); i++) {
        group.getChildAt(i).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    TextView name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.canteen_line_name);
    convertView.setTag(name);

    name.setText(line.getName());

    return convertView;
}
```

My problem is now that the child items seem to randomly appear or disappear in their group and nothing is "in order" like it should be. Is there a mistake in my code or did i miss something?